# Listening to Key_events at background

Tags: blackberry

I want My App to listen to Key_events while running in the background.My app does so when it is running in the foreground but is not able to do so while running in the background

Comment: i certainly hope that the OS doesn't let you do that (for security reasons)

Comment: possible duplicate of [BlackBerry app that runs in background and intercepts all times a key is pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489857/blackberry-app-that-runs-in-background-and-intercepts-all-times-a-key-is-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

Button press and key press events are are restricted, though the restriction varies with OS version. With the latest versions background processes can receive volume and call control events. As Nate hopes, no background process will receive key press events that may disclose protected information.

Comment: :] If you don't like sharing your secrets with people who write fart apps buy a BlackBerry.